# Angular updating a list doesn't work after first (seemingly) successful delete

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am following the Angular hero tutorial while using Ionic to build a task list. I am at the 'http' part of the tutorial but got stuck at deleting tasks using RxJS.

What happened:

1. Swipe on a task, the task is deleted from the view.
2. Afterwards, deletion (swipe or click) no longer works with any of the remaining tasks.
3. Also, adding a task using a sibling component partially works (as reported by the "message" component), but added tasks no longer show up on the task list.
4. Updating any remaining task seemingly still works.

I first suspected it was some conflict with Ionic, but even if I changed the swipe action to normal clicking events, the same thing happens.

Here are the codes for related components. Any help will be much appreciated!

You can find the code here: https://github.com/hktang/butler

#### tasks.page.html

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Tasks</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <ion-list>
    <app-task-input [tasks]="tasks"></app-task-input>
    <app-task-list 
      [tasks]="tasks"
      (selectedTaskChange)="onSelectedTaskChange($event)"
    ></app-task-list>
  </ion-list>

  <app-task-detail [task]="selectedTask"></app-task-detail>

  <app-messages></app-messages>

</ion-content>
```

#### tasks.page.ts

```typescript
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Task } from "./task";
import { TaskService } from "./task.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-tasks",
  templateUrl: "./tasks.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["./tasks.page.scss"]
})
export class TasksPage implements OnInit {
  selectedTask: Task;
  tasks: Task[];

  constructor(private taskService: TaskService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTasks();
  }

  getTasks(): void {
    this.taskService.getTasks().subscribe(tasks => (this.tasks = tasks));
  }

  onSelectedTaskChange(task: Task): void {
    this.selectedTask = task;
  }
}
```

#### task.service.ts

```typescript
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { Task } from "./task";
import { MessageService } from "../messages/message.service";
import { catchError, map, tap } from "rxjs/operators";

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json" })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class TaskService {
  private tasksUrl = "api/tasks";

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private messageService: MessageService
  ) {}

 ...

  /** DELETE: delete the hero from the server */
  deleteTask(task: Task | number): Observable<Task> {
    const id = typeof task === 'number' ? task : task.id;
    const url = `${this.tasksUrl}/${id}`;

    return this.http.delete<Task>(url, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`deleted task id=${id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Task>('deleteTask'))
    );
  }

 ...
}
```

#### task-list.component.html

```html
<ion-list *ngIf="tasks">
  <ion-item-sliding
    *ngFor="let task of tasks"
    (ionSwipe)="markDone(task)">

    <ion-item
      (click)="onSelect(task)"
      [class.selected]="task === selectedTask">
      <ion-label>{{task.name}}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item-options side="right">
      <button ion-button (click)="markDone(task)">Done</button>
    </ion-item-options>

  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

### task-list.component.ts

```typescript
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Input, Output } from "@angular/core";
import { Task } from "../task";
import { TaskService } from "../task.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-task-list",
  templateUrl: "./task-list.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./task-list.component.scss"]
})
export class TaskListComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedTask: Task;

  @Input()
  tasks: Task[];

  @Output()
  selectedTaskChange = new EventEmitter<Task>();

  constructor(private taskService: TaskService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onSelect(task: Task): void {
    this.selectedTask = task;
    this.selectedTaskChange.emit(task);
  }

  markDone(task: Task){
    this.tasks = this.tasks.filter(tsk => tsk !== task);
    this.taskService.deleteTask(task).subscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: what error appears?

Comment: Strangely there's no error message from the console or from the build process. @Microsmsm

Comment: try an operator by operator like this: ```import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
```

Comment: Thanks @Microsmsm,  I have `import { catchError, map, tap } from "rxjs/operators";` in the `task.service`, but it is never used. Where should it go..?

Comment: was you be able to fix the problem?

Comment: @Microsmsm I tried your answer but it doesn't work. Let me get a StackBlitz up an running then share the link with you.. thanks for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183401/discussion-between-john-doe-and-microsmsm).

Answer (score 1):

changing the code of showing tasks to just this should fix the problem

```html
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let task of tasks" (ionSwipe)="markDone(task)">
  <ion-item>{{task.name}}</ion-item>
  <ion-item-options> </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this works. I also found my original code was using ionic3 but I am using ionic 4. Now the problem is, I can add tasks, but the task doesn't show up (after making delete action).

Comment: Also I don't understand why adding an <ionic-item-option> inside the "options" group breaks the code..?